# Debian - problem related to procmail

Tags: linux, debian, postfix

recently I started getting an error like that:

> This is the mail system at host xxx.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could notbe
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You candelete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> The mail system
>
> : Command time limit exceeded: "procmail -a "$EXTENSION""

This is happening on  Debian linux with Postfix installed into it. I have lost ideas where to look for the problems. All of the mails are located in /home folder. I guess it's local maildir.

Comment: First step is to do `df` and see if any partitions are full (close to 95%, because usually 5% is reserved for root). If that's not the problem: Postfix calls `procmail` to "deliver" the mail to the user, so find out which user that is, and if there's a `.procmailrc` for this user, look at which additional tasks it does.

Comment: Hello @dirkt I have checked everythnig, the space for hard disk is fine. The bounces seem to happen for few last users. For example user A is sending an email with attachements which is around ~500KB to 100 people (he is also adding some with CC and also BCC). For example the list has 100 emails which 90 people is reciving the emails and 10 randomly emails are bounced (status=bounced). So for now I have figured out few things which I may try, but also asking here and if someone may help me.Thank you.

Comment: If it only happens for emails with sizeable attachments, one obvious guess is that  `procmail` is configured on your systems to do something with those attachments, and it takes too long. Have you enabled logging for `procmail`?

Comment: Hello @dirkt once again and thank you for the answer. Yes I have been able to login to the procmail via webmin to see and check it. Also I have noticed that procmail config is kind of strange and one line of code is confusing me. This "script": 
:0fw: spamassassin.lock * 
< 256000 
| /usr/bin/spamc
the question is, is my instict of bouncing status right and if I should change the 256000 kb for higher value or lower. What do you think, sir?

Comment: See `man procmailrc` and `man procmailex` for details. Line breaks are significant, but that line probably means "let spamassassin inspect all mails of size less than 256K'. It's possible that spamassassin needs to inspect *all* mails to deliver them, but I'd have to see the complete script to judge that'. It's also possible there's a problem with lockfiles held, which cause the timeout.

Comment: Once again I am grateful for your tips @dirkt What do I need to check in the manual of procmailrc and procmailex? Where should I look? Um that's the complete "script" for that, I thought of increasing it to like 512kbs or sth in order to let it pass and not bounce the messages with attachements. Lockfile? What do you mean? Thank you once again from the bottom of my heart :)

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is, so what I'd do is experiment: Remove the complete file (or replace it with an empty file), modify the file so it doesn't use locking, and yes, if you want, play around with the size limit. See what happens, and if any changes make the problem go away, or appear more often, etc. In particular if you don't need spamassassin I'd think about chaning that file permanently.